Edit WooCommerce Shop page with Elementor issue
I am making my first WordPress website using Elementor. When I try to edit my shop page of my ecommerce website which shows all the products, it shows the error which states that my shop page is a Product archive, and I should use theme builder  to create a shop archive template instead.
After looking up on Google and YouTube, it seems my shop page should be using a product archive template which only shows one product at a time, and that I need to create a Shop archive template. However, Elementor is asking me to upgrade to pro to create a new archive.
This wasn't the issue earlier and I could easily edit the page, but one day it randomly decided to stop working. Here is the screen shot of the error.
Error while trying to edit shop page using elementor
Maybe I am not understanding the issue here, or maybe I have understood something wrong regards to what needs to be done to fix it. Please help.
I have tried deactivating various plugins to see if they are causing the issue. I even tried making a new shop page with Shop archive and editing the archive type of the shop page too, but couldn't do any of that.
